# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 546: ordinal not in range(128) only with lots of text

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, smtplib

I am getting the above error when trying to run an automated email script. If I delete most of the body of the email it works fine. However, when I add over some number of characters (all are upper/lower case or numbers) I get the error. I tried changing the code in `smtplib.py` but then my script stopped working.

This is my code:

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp endpoint', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('login', sys.argv[1])

for name, email in unmessagedmembers.items():
    body = """Subject: Research\na {} lot of text 
n more text""".format(name)

print('Sending email to {}...'.format(email))


sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('me@email.com', email, body)

if sendmailStatus != {}:
    print('There was a problem sending email to {}: {}'.format(email, sendmailStatus))

smtpObj.quit()
```

it is saying I get the error on the line:

```
sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('me@email.com', email, body)
```

Comment: You're giving it a string, which will be encoded to bytes using the ASCII codec, as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html). If you want to send text beyond basic ASCII, you need to encode the string yourself to bytes first.

Comment: I did this .encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii') per another stack question but then certain mailboxes block the message.

Comment: `\u2019` is a `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` (`’` as opposed to ASCII quote `'`) and is not an ASCII character.  Your "lots of text" must contain one.

Comment: Please first search for the error message before asking yet another question on it. Also, provide a [mcve], so people can reproduce the issue. In most cases, you'll find the error yourself that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, all the suggestions worked. I guess I wasn't understanding the solution on first review.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) states: "msg may be a string containing characters in the ASCII range, or a byte string. A string is encoded to bytes using the ascii codec, and lone \r and \n characters are converted to \r\n characters. A byte string is not modified."

Since `email` is likely a string, Python tries to encoded it using the ASCII codec when you call `smtpObj.sendmail()`, and the encoding comes down to:

```
email.encode('ascii')
```

If you were to run that line, you're likely to see the same error message.

To avoid it, encode `email` yourself and then pass it to `smtpObj.sendmail()`:

```
    email.encode()  # by default will use utf8 in modern Python
    sendmailStatus = smtpObj.sendmail('me@email.com', email, body')
```

Note that your example code has errors in the indentation, I assumed all the code was indented to be within the `for` block.

However, whether that causes problems on the receiving end is a different matter - you can try replacing any character outside the ASCII range with other characters, or look into adding headers that instruct the recipient to  decode the message using the correct encoding.

Comment: Isn't the [quopri encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) pretty standard in emails?